# Codeigniter insert double quotes once

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, escaping

Hi I have the following insert:

```
$full_pjt_save = array(
        'img_copertina' => $this->input->post('copertine'),
        'physical_already' => $this->input->post('physical_already'),
        'physical_format_product' => $this->input->post('formato_fisico'),
        'physical_format' => $this->input->post('physical_format'),
        'physical_format_vinile' => $this->input->post('formato_vinile'),
        'physical_boxqty' => $this->input->post('physical_boxqty'),
        'physical_tot_time' => $this->input->post('physical_tot_time'),
        'physical_qty' => $this->input->post('physical_qty'),
        'sale_price' => $this->input->post('sale_price'),
        'keywords' => $this->input->post('keywords'),
        'descrizione' => $this->input->post('descrizione'),
        'durata' => $this->input->post('durata'),
        );

$added_fields = $full_pjt_save+array('last_mod' => time());
$this->db->where('id_acquisto', $this->input->post('id_acquisto'));
$save_full_pjt_to_db = $this->db->update('progetti_'.$pjt_table, $added_fields);
$pjt_table_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

This works fine, but I have a dropdown item where 'formato_vinile' is this:

`45 Giri (7" Singolo, 45 Giri)`

but gets inserted in the db cut after the double-quotes:

`45 Giri (7`

Is there a way to write it in full?

Comment: i guess the problem is already in the post() method since CI do an internal xss prevention. `$config['global_xss_filtering']` in the config.php. check the documentation about [set](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert), there is a optional flag to disable escaping. it may be usefull for your case

Answer (score 0):

just escape your input `$this->input->post(mysqli::escape_string ('formato_vinile'))`

Apologies not a static call that was a bit of psuedo code though in CI (I am not a user)

```
$this->db->escape_str() ;
```

Comment: there should be also a helper function included in CI [Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html)

Comment: @KURN I don't see any, I tried with `$this->db->escape_str($this->input->post('formato_vinile'))` but nothing...

Comment: @Shaun Hare This is the result: Fatal error: Non-static method mysqli::escape_string() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Answer (score 0):

ok since i cant write it as comment cause of the code... here my idea:

its quick&dirty so you should modificate it a bit.

```
$added_fields = $full_pjt_save+array('last_mod' => time());
$this->db->where('id_acquisto', $this->input->post('id_acquisto'));
$this->db->set('physical_format_vinile', $this->input->post('formato_vinile'), FALSE);
$save_full_pjt_to_db = $this->db->update('progetti_'.$pjt_table, $added_fields);
$pjt_table_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

note to unset/delete the key physical_format_vinile from your `$added_fields` array

its not tested but i hope it helps or give you an idea how to handle your problem.

*edit lets maybe check where is the exactly problem. can you do a `var_dump($this->input->post('formato_vinile'))` and check if the double quotes are still correct?

Comment: var_dum shows this: `string(10) "45 Giri (7"`. So I thought was the input so I tried `var_dump($_POST['formato_vinile']);` with the same exact result.

Comment: @Mr.Web so the Problem is already in your input and has (for now) nothing to do with your database stuff. check in config.php `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';` and add the double quote `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\"';`. CI's post method automaticly prevent from xss attacks by blocking defined signs

Comment: I did that but still nothing changes. Same output.

Comment: can you put `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` and try it again (only for testing of course)? so we can beter localize where the problem is.

Comment: I did but same result. (I also removed the `$this->db->set...` as it was giving me errors and tried).